# Passenger EBADF file descriptor exception 502

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, passenger, rack

Since we upgraded our app to Rails 4.1.12 and Rack 1.5.5 due to the CVEs, we seem to be getting random 502's appear. Approx 1% of requests and I cannot consistently re-create the issue, only observe it (which is extremely frustrating, as you can imagine). We had been running 4.1.8 and rack 1.5.2 ... I tried downgrading Rack and still observing the issues however due to the nature of compliance, etc going back to Rails 4.1.8 could be quite complex.

We're using Passenger 5.0.6 (prod) and 5.0.13 (staging) with Ruby 2.1.5 with nginx.

The pattern I see is:

```
nginx-error:  [ 2015-07-12 16:12:05.3947 2176/7f97fb7fe700 age/Hel/Req/Utils.cpp:89 ]: [Client 7-50] Sending 502 response: application did not send a     complete response
nginx-error:  App 2210 stderr: [ 2015-07-12 16:12:05.9232 2813/0x007f6eb5056088(Worker 1) utils.rb:85 ]: *** Exception Errno::EBADF in Passenger     RequestHandler's client socket (Bad file descriptor - writev()) (process 2813, thread 0x007f6eb5056088(Worker 1)):
nginx-error:  App 2210 stderr: #011from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/ruby_core_io_enhancements.rb:41:in `writev'
nginx-error:  App 2210 stderr: #011from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/ruby_core_io_enhancements.rb:41:in `writev'
nginx-error:  App 2210 stderr: #011from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils/unseekable_socket.rb:126:in `writev'
nginx-error:  App 2210 stderr: #011from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:177:in `process_body'
nginx-error:  App 2210 stderr: #011from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:104:in `process_request'
nginx-error:  App 2210 stderr: #011from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:149:in     `accept_and_process_next_request'
nginx-error:  App 2210 stderr: #011from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:110:in `main_loop'
nginx-error:  App 2210 stderr: #011from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:414:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
nginx-error:  App 2210 stderr: #011from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:111:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'
```

I have raised this question on IRC #passenger and haven't seen anyone experiencing the same issue. Any hints on how to figure out what exactly is causing this?

Comment: Was the Passenger compiled with Nginx as a module? If so, please show the version of Nginx and this particular Passenger module

Comment: We installed passenger using the official deb repo from Phusion ...

Comment: Don't know a specific solution, but this article, which talks about how Passenger's "smart" spawning option (which is its default for Ruby apps) can lead to this "Bad file descriptor" error: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/ruby/spawn_methods/#unintentional-file-descriptor-sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passenger author here.

I believe this issue is caused by something in the app, maybe a gem -- not Passenger. The EBADF error was raised from the application, so it's likely that some gem, probably one with a native extension, closed a wrong file descriptor. But which gem it is, I have no idea. The standard way to debug this is to disable gems one by one until you have found the culprit. This can be hard if your code relies on gems, but there aren't many ways to handle this.

Comment: Thanks @hongli ... really appreciated, we've been banging our heads against the wall however we are slowly coming to the same conclusion however painful this debugging might be. I'll post back when we find what happened or at least how we magically fixed it :)